# How do I add 1 number to a array?

Tags: c#

I do not have anything other than the normal

```
using System;

namespace TryStuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

And I know that having nothing at the start and still asking questions isnt highly looked on but STILL...

Im trying to create a code that asks you for an integer, and if you answer anything over 0, it ADDS the given number to an array, once you stop giving numbers (example type some "stop") it prints out ALL the numbers given to the array.

I DO NOT need the full code for something like this, just an answer to how do I append to an array without making it insanely complicated (things ive found on the google are like 20 lines of code but im pretty sure its not that hard).

Sorry for the long post and in short, how do I append to an array? If you can provide me a code, please implement it in the C# code or give me a "explanation" how to do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could use a generic array List<int> instead of a simple array. Simple arrays are fixed-sized, but generic arrays are more flexible in size and type.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use an array, you want a different data structure that allows easy expansion, like `List<T>`.  For `List<T>`, you simply call `.Add`, like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TryStuff
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var myList = new List<int>();
      while(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int x))
      {
        if (x > 0)
        {
          myList.Add(x);
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + string.Join(",", myList));
    }
  }
}
```

This should keep allowing you to enter integer numbers and add them to the list if the number is greater than 0.  It ignores all numbers 0 or less than 0.  If you type anything that is not a number, it will stop and print out the list you entered.

Comment: Hey, if you write example. 10 and press enter, it instantly outputs "You entered:" and doesnt even print the list. Is there a typo somewhere because the code seems perfect to me, im still new so im trying to figure out if im pressing the wrong key.

Comment: @JannaJokiranta Yes, there was a small error in the code, sorry.  I accidentally flipped the while exit condition.  I've corrected the answer.